# Google geocode API not returning result for certain locations

Tags: php, android, ios, google-api, google-geocoding-api

Google Geocode API is not returning result for certain locations. One of them is

```
Perkins Restaurant & Bakery, East Fowler Ave, Tampa, FL
```

Below is link of result API returns for this location.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Perkins%20Restaurant%20&%20Bakery,%20E%20Fowler%20Ave,%20Tampa,%20FL,%20United%20States&sensor=true

Has anyone faced this issue? I don't provide `components` parameter so search result should not be restricted to any geographical area.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps geocode api inconsistencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976446/google-maps-geocode-api-inconsistencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You need to replace & in the address argument by its URL-encoding %26"

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6979738/189804

With the ampersand:

`{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}`

With %26 encoding:

```
    {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "2301",
               "short_name" : "2301",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "East Fowler Avenue",
... and so on ...
```

Comment: Replacing `&` with `%26` works but escaping all characters does not work. `place = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef) place,
                                                                                     NULL, CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]\" "),
                                                                                     kCFStringEncodingUTF8));` Can you explain why is this?

Comment: I'd have to look at Google API docs to see what the requirements are and escape only what they say to escape.